# Cannot get NSTimer with firedate to work properly on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I am trying to create a timer with a duration of 1 minute, that repeats every minute, but starts at the beginning of the next minute of actual time (like 5:21:00pm). Per a similar post I found on here, I am using this code for it:

```
@IBAction func switchEnabled(value: Bool) {
    if(value){
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
        components.minute += 1
        components.second = 0
        let nextMinuteDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
        let doneTimer = NSTimer(fireDate: nextMinuteDate!, interval: 60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDone:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(doneTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        // still not working properly
    }
    else{
        print("switch off")
        // invalidate timer here
    }
}
```

my timerDone selector just prints out "Done!", but when I run this on the watchOS 2 simulator and activate the switch, it immediately prints done and the timer starts for a minute, so it is not waiting until the firedate. Any ideas on what is going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test: UIViewController{
   override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         let date = NSDate()
         let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
         let components = calendar.components([.Second], fromDate: date)
         let delayedStart:Double=(Double)(60-components.second)
         let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayedStart * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
         dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDone:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true).fire()
         })
       }
     func timerDone(myObj:NSObject){
          print("Done")
     }
}
```

1. To fire exactly after the next minute, first you need to get the number of completed seconds in the current minute and then subtract it from 60 to get the next minute.
2. Once those seconds completes you have to fire immediately.
3. Then, you know how to repeat the timer with certain interval (in this case 60sec).

Please let me know if you face any difficulties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. So as you can see, I have all of this in an action tied to a switch on the watch. So when I turn off the switch, I want the timer to stop. How can I invalidate the timer in this case? Thanks.

Comment: create a NSTimer variable in your class like var myTimer = NSTimer(). Then do this--> myTimer =NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDone:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) myTimer.fire(). You can call myTimer.invalidate() in your button action to stop the timer.

Comment: BTW, you can give a point / mark the answer as correct, it may be useful for others

Comment: Thanks a lot, should be able to figure everything out from here. And yes I marked it as correct and gave a point yesterday, but I don't have enough rep for the point to be publicly displayed yet, but it's there :)